# Spark sort by key and then group by to get ordered iterable?

Tags: sorting, apache-spark

I have a Pair RDD `(K, V)` with the key containing a  `time` and an `ID`. I would like to get a Pair RDD of the form `(K, Iterable<V>)` where the keys are groupped by id and the iterable is ordered by time.

I'm currently using `sortByKey().groupByKey()` and my tests seem to prove it works, however I'm reading that it may not always be the case, as discussed in this question with diverging answers ( [Does groupByKey in Spark preserve the original order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206660/does-groupbykey-in-spark-preserve-the-original-order) ).

Is it correct or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Please put a bounty on the other question, if you need better answers. This is a duplicate of the question you mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The answer from Matei](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Is-shuffle-stable-tp7628p7633.html), who I consider authoritative on this topic,  is quite clear:

> The order is not guaranteed actually, only which keys end up in each
>   partition. Reducers may fetch data from map tasks in an arbitrary
>   order, depending on which ones are available first. If you’d like a
>   specific order, you should sort each partition. Here you might be
>   getting it because each partition only ends up having one element, and
>   collect() does return the partitions in order.

In that context, a better option would be to apply the sorting to the resulting collections per key:

```
rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(_.sorted)
```

Comment: Right, depends on the dataset (number of duplicate keys), but it's better to do the sorting on less "rows", after they have already been collapsed by grouping.

Comment: @MarkoBonaci that's what's going on here. After `groupByKey` the resulting grouping is sorted to meet the requirements in the question. I'm not sure what the comment is about. Could you clarify?

Comment: I was just confirming your last sentence and trying to explain the reason why that's better. We're cool :)

Comment: @maasg It is written in spark docs to avoid groupByKey if possible. However it seems to me that to sort within a group this seems to be the only alternative. Is there some other way in which we can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

The [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations) offers three alternatives if one desires predictably ordered data following shuffle:

> - `mapPartitions` to sort each partition using, for example, `.sorted`
> - `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` to efficiently sort partitions while simultaneously repartitioning
> - `sortBy` to make a globally ordered RDD

As written in the [Spark API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions@repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(partitioner:org.apache.spark.Partitioner):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K,V)]), `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` is more efficient than calling repartition and then sorting within each partition because it can push the sorting down into the shuffle machinery.

The sorting, however, is computed by looking only at the keys `K` of tuples `(K, V)`. The trick is to put all the relevant informations in the first element of the tuple, like `((K, V), null)`, defining a custom partitioner and a custom ordering. [This article](http://codingjunkie.net/spark-secondary-sort/) descrives pretty well the technique.