# Removing duplicate rows based on Java DataFrame

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame which contains the following details.

```
|id|Name|Country|version|
|1 |Jack|UK     |new    |
|1 |Jack|USA    |old    |
|2 |Rose|Germany|new    |
|3 |Sam |France |old    |
```

I would like to create a DataFrame where, if the data is duplicate based on "id" it picks the **new** *version* over the **old** *version* as so

```
|id|Name|Country|version|
|1 |Jack|UK     |new    |
|2 |Rose|Germany|new    |
|3 |Sam |France |old    |
```

What is the best way to do this in Java/Spark, or do I have to use some sort of nested SQL query?

The simplified SQL version would look something like below:

```
WITH new_version AS (
    SELECT
      ad.id
      ,ad.name
      ,ad.country
      ,ad.version
    FROM allData ad
    WHERE ad.version = 'new'
),
old_version AS (
    SELECT
      ad.id
      ,ad.name
      ,ad.country
      ,ad.version
    FROM allData ad
    LEF JOIN new_version nv on nv.id = ad.id
    WHERE ad.version = 'old'
      AND nv.id is null
),

SELECT id, name, country, version FROM new_version
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, country, version FROM old_version
```

Comment: So you have only one record with "new" and one with "old" at most? No possibility to have several "old"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older versions of Spark you can use `orderBy` in combination with `groupBy`. According to the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505599/spark-dataframe-does-groupby-after-orderby-maintain-that-order), the order should be kept after a `groupBy` if the dataframe is sorted after that column. Hence, the following should work (note that the `orderBy` is on both the `id` and `version` columns):

```
val df2 = df.orderBy("id", "version")
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(first("Name").as("Name"), first("Country").as("Country"), first("version").as("version"))
```

This will yield the following result

```
+---+----+-------+-------+
| id|Name|Country|version|
+---+----+-------+-------+
|  3| Sam| France|    old|
|  1|Jack|     UK|    new|
|  2|Rose|Germany|    new|
+---+----+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have a `dataframe` as

```
+---+----+-------+-------+
|id |Name|Country|version|
+---+----+-------+-------+
|1  |Jack|UK     |new    |
|1  |Jack|USA    |old    |
|2  |Rose|Germany|new    |
|3  |Sam |France |old    |
+---+----+-------+-------+
```

which is created using

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1","Jack","UK","new"),
  ("1","Jack","USA","old"),
  ("2","Rose","Germany","new"),
  ("3","Sam","France","old")
).toDF("id","Name","Country","version")
```

You can achieve your requirement of given *sql query* as **removing all the duplucated *id* rows with `old` as *version* column** using `Window`, `rank`, `filter` and `drop` functions as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("version")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec))
  .filter(!(col("version") === "old" && col("rank") > 1))
  .drop("rank")
```

You should get final `dataframe` as

```
+---+----+-------+-------+
|id |Name|Country|version|
+---+----+-------+-------+
|3  |Sam |France |old    |
|1  |Jack|UK     |new    |
|2  |Rose|Germany|new    |
+---+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Seems like I cannot use window function in spark 1.6 any ways around the rank function ?

Comment: you should go with groupBy, orderBy and agg for that case