# Is it safe to sort before grouping a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Given a pyspark dataframe `df` with columns 'ProductId', 'Date' and 'Price', how safe is to sort by 'Date' and assume that `func.first('Price')` will always retrieve the Price corresponding to the minimum date?

I mean: will
`df.orderBy('ProductId', 'Date').groupBy('ProductId').agg(func.first('Price'))`
return for each product the first price paid in time without messing with the `orderBy` while grouping?

Comment: I also found [this scala post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505599/spark-dataframe-does-groupby-after-orderby-maintain-that-order) where the accepted answer says that order is preserved, but the discussion in the comments and other answers say otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the order is guaranteed to be maintained for the `groupBy()`. However, here is alternative way to do what you want that will work.

Use [`pyspark.sql.Window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) to partition and order the DataFrame as desired. Then use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.distinct()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.distinct) to drop the duplicate entries.

For example:

**Create Dummy Data**

```python
data = [
    (123, '2017-07-01', 50),
    (123, '2017-01-01', 100),
    (345, '2018-01-01', 20),
    (123, '2017-03-01', 25),
    (345, '2018-02-01', 33)
]

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ['ProductId', 'Date', 'Price'])
df.show()
#+---------+----------+-----+
#|ProductId|      Date|Price|
#+---------+----------+-----+
#|      123|2017-07-01|   50|
#|      123|2017-01-01|  100|
#|      345|2018-01-01|   20|
#|      123|2017-03-01|   25|
#|      345|2018-02-01|   33|
#+---------+----------+-----+
```

**Use Window**

Use `Window.partitionBy('ProductId').orderBy('Date')`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df.select(
    'ProductId',
    f.first('Price').over(Window.partitionBy('ProductId').orderBy('Date')).alias('Price')
).distinct().show()
#+---------+-----+
#|ProductId|Price|
#+---------+-----+
#|      123|  100|
#|      345|   20|
#+---------+-----+
```

**Edit**

I found [this scala post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505599/spark-dataframe-does-groupby-after-orderby-maintain-that-order) in which the accepted answer says that the order is preserved, though there is a discussion in the comments that contradicts that.

Comment: Well, I need to group by because i need to aggregate on other columns. My real case is a bit more complicated.

Comment: You can extend this to multiple aggregations. Just add more items to the `select` statement. You can also define the window outside to save typing: `w = Window.partitionBy('ProductId').orderBy('Date')` and then simplify to `f.first('Price').over(w).alias(...)`

Comment: Isn't it possible to use the window function inside the aggregator of a groupby? Like `df.groupBy('Product).agg(f.first('Price').over(w).alias('First price'))`, where `w=Window.partitionBy('Product').orderby('Date')`.

Comment: I couldn't get that syntax to work (doesn't mean it's not possible).