# how compute discounted future cumulative sum with spark pyspark window functions or sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

Can I compute a discounted future cumulative sum using spark sql? Below is an example that computes the undiscounted cum future sum using window functions, and I hard coded in what I mean by the discounted cum sum:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


def undiscountedCummulativeFutureReward(df):
    windowSpec = Window \
        .partitionBy('user') \
        .orderBy('time') \
        .rangeBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

    tot_reward = F.sum('reward').over(windowSpec)

    df_tot_reward = df.withColumn('undiscounted', tot_reward)
    return df_tot_reward


def makeData(spark, gamma=0.5):
    data = [{'user': 'bob', 'time': 3, 'reward': 10, 'discounted_cum': 10 + (gamma * 9) + ((gamma ** 2) * 11)},
            {'user': 'bob', 'time': 4, 'reward': 9, 'discounted_cum': 9 + gamma * 11},
            {'user': 'bob', 'time': 5, 'reward': 11, 'discounted_cum': 11.0},
            {'user': 'jo', 'time': 4, 'reward': 6, 'discounted_cum': 6 + gamma * 7},
            {'user': 'jo', 'time': 5, 'reward': 7, 'discounted_cum': 7.0},
            ]
    schema = T.StructType([T.StructField('user', T.StringType(), False),
                           T.StructField('time', T.IntegerType(), False),
                           T.StructField('reward', T.IntegerType(), False),
                           T.StructField('discounted_cum', T.FloatType(), False)])

    return spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)


def main(spark):
    df = makeData(spark)
    df = undiscountedCummulativeFutureReward(df)
    df.orderBy('user', 'time').show()
    return df
```

When you run it you get:

```
+----+----+------+--------------+------------+
|user|time|reward|discounted_cum|undiscounted|
+----+----+------+--------------+------------+
| bob|   3|    10|         17.25|          30|
| bob|   4|     9|          14.5|          20|
| bob|   5|    11|          11.0|          11|
|  jo|   4|     6|           9.5|          13|
|  jo|   5|     7|           7.0|           7|
+----+----+------+--------------+------------+
```

That is discounted is `sum \gamma^k r_k for k=0 to \infinity`

I'm wondering if I can compute the discounted column with Window functions, like introduce a column with the rank, a literal with gamma, multiply things together - but still not quite clear - I suppose I can do it with some kind of UDF, but I think I'd have to first `collect_as_list` all the users, return a new list with the cum discounted sum, and then explode the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you were starting with the following DataFrame:

```python
df.show()
#+----+----+------+
#|user|time|reward|
#+----+----+------+
#| bob|   3|    10|
#| bob|   4|     9|
#| bob|   5|    11|
#|  jo|   4|     6|
#|  jo|   5|     7|
#+----+----+------+
```

You can join this DataFrame to itself on the `user` column, and keep only those rows where the `time` column of the right table is greater than or equal to the time column of the left table. We make this easier by aliasing the DataFrames `l` and `r`.

After the join, you can group by `user`, `time` and `reward` from the left table and aggregate the reward column from the right table. However it seems that a [`groupBy` followed by an `orderBy` is not guaranteed to maintain that order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505599/spark-dataframe-does-groupby-after-orderby-maintain-that-order), so you should use a `Window` to be explicit.

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as f

w = Window.partitionBy("user", "l.time", "l.reward").orderBy("r.time")

df = df.alias("l").join(df.alias("r"), on="user")\
    .where("r.time>=l.time")\
    .select(
        "user",
        f.col("l.time").alias("time"),
        f.col("l.reward").alias("reward"),
        f.collect_list("r.reward").over(w).alias("rewards")
    )

df.show()
#+----+----+------+-----------+
#|user|time|reward|    rewards|
#+----+----+------+-----------+
#|  jo|   4|     6|        [6]|
#|  jo|   4|     6|     [6, 7]|
#|  jo|   5|     7|        [7]|
#| bob|   3|    10|       [10]|
#| bob|   3|    10|    [10, 9]|
#| bob|   3|    10|[10, 9, 11]|
#| bob|   4|     9|        [9]|
#| bob|   4|     9|    [9, 11]|
#| bob|   5|    11|       [11]|
#+----+----+------+-----------+
```

Now you have all of the elements required to compute your `discounted_cum` column.

#### Spark 2.1 and above:

You can use `pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode` to explode the `rewards` array along with the index in the list. This will make a new row for each value in the `rewards` array. Use `distinct` to drop duplicates that were introduced by using the `Window` function (instead of `groupBy`).

We'll call the index `k` and the reward `rk`. Now you can apply your function using `pyspark.sql.functions.pow`

```python
gamma = 0.5

df.select("user", "time", "reward", f.posexplode("rewards").alias("k", "rk"))\
    .distinct()\
    .withColumn("discounted", f.pow(f.lit(gamma), f.col("k"))*f.col("rk"))\
    .groupBy("user", "time")\
    .agg(f.first("reward").alias("reward"), f.sum("discounted").alias("discounted_cum"))\
    .show()
#+----+----+------+--------------+
#|user|time|reward|discounted_cum|
#+----+----+------+--------------+
#| bob|   3|    10|         17.25|
#| bob|   4|     9|          14.5|
#| bob|   5|    11|          11.0|
#|  jo|   4|     6|           9.5|
#|  jo|   5|     7|           7.0|
#+----+----+------+--------------+
```

#### Older Versions of Spark

For older versions of spark, you'll have to use `row_number()-1` to get the values for `k` after using `explode`:

```python
df.select("user", "time", "reward", f.explode("rewards").alias("rk"))\
    .distinct()\
    .withColumn(
        "k",
        f.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("user", "time").orderBy("time"))-1
    )\
    .withColumn("discounted", f.pow(f.lit(gamma), f.col("k"))*f.col("rk"))\
    .groupBy("user", "time")\
    .agg(f.first("reward").alias("reward"), f.sum("discounted").alias("discounted_cum"))\
    .show()
#+----+----+------+--------------+
#|user|time|reward|discounted_cum|
#+----+----+------+--------------+
#|  jo|   4|     6|           9.5|
#|  jo|   5|     7|           7.0|
#| bob|   3|    10|         17.25|
#| bob|   4|     9|          14.5|
#| bob|   5|    11|          11.0|
#+----+----+------+--------------+
```