# String aggregation and group by in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset that has Id, Value and Timestamp columns. Id and Value columns are strings. Sample:

| Id | Value | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | 100 | 1658919600 |
| Id1 | 200 | 1658919602 |
| Id1 | 300 | 1658919601 |
| Id2 | 433 | 1658919677 |

I want to concatenate Values that belong to the same Id, and order them by Timestamp. E.g. for rows with Id1 the result would look like:

| Id | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Id1 | 100;300;200 |

Some pseudo code would be:

```
res = SELECT Id,
      STRING_AGG(Value,";") WITHING GROUP ORDER BY Timestamp AS Values
      FROM table
      GROUP BY Id
```

Can someone help me write this in Databricks? PySpark and SQL are both fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can collect lists of struct of`Timestamp` and `Value` (in that order) for each `Id`, sort them (`sort_array` will sort by the first value of struct, i.e `Timestamp`) and combine `Value`'s values into string using `concat_ws`.

PySpark (Spark 3.1.2)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df
 .groupBy("Id")
 .agg(F.expr("concat_ws(';', sort_array(collect_list(struct(Timestamp, Value))).Value) as Values"))
).show(truncate=False)

# +---+-----------+
# |Id |Values     |
# +---+-----------+
# |Id1|100;300;200|
# |Id2|433        |
# +---+-----------+
```

in SparkSQL

```
SELECT Id, concat_ws(';', sort_array(collect_list(struct(Timestamp, Value))).Value) as Values
FROM table
GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a beautiful question!! This is a perfect use case for [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) which can port Python and Pandas code to PySpark. I think this is something that is hard to express in Spark but easy to express in native Python or Pandas.

Let's just concern ourselves with 1 ID first. For one ID, using pure native Python, it would look like below. Assume the Timestamps are already sorted when this is applied.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Id": ["Id1", "Id1", "Id1", "Id2","Id2","Id2"],
                   "Value": [100,200,300,433, 500,600],
                   "Timestamp": [1658919600, 1658919602, 1658919601, 1658919677, 1658919670, 1658919672]})

from typing import Iterable, List, Dict, Any

def logic(df: List[Dict[str,Any]]) -> Iterable[Dict[str,Any]]:
    _id = df[0]['Id']
    items = []
    for row in df:
        items.append(row['Value'])
    yield {"Id": _id, "Values": items}
```

Now we can call Fugue with one line of code to run this on Pandas. Fugue uses the type annotation from the `logic` function to handle conversions for you as it enters the function. We can run this for 1 ID (not sorted yet).

```
from fugue import transform
transform(df.loc[df["Id"] == "Id1"], logic, schema="Id:str,Values:[int]")
```

and that generates this:

```
    Id  Values
0   Id1 [100, 200, 300]
```

Now we are ready to bring it to Spark. All we need to do is add the engine and partitioning strategy to the `transform` call.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = transform(df, 
                logic, 
                schema="Id:str,Values:[int]", 
                partition={"by": "Id", "presort": "Timestamp asc"}, 
                engine=spark)
sdf.show()
```

Because we passed in the SparkSession, this code will run on Spark.`sdf` is a SparkDataFrame so we need `.show()` because it evaluates lazily. Schema is a requirement for Spark so we need it too on Fugue but it's significantly simplified. The partitioning strategy will run `logic` on each Id, and will sort the items by Timestamp for each partition.

For the FugueSQL version, you can do:

```py
from fugue_sql import fsql

fsql(
"""
SELECT * 
FROM df
TRANSFORM PREPARTITION BY Id PRESORT Timestamp ASC USING logic SCHEMA Id:str,Values:[int]
PRINT
"""
).run(spark)
```

Comment: This will run on Databricks no problem btw because it uses the SparkSession available. Just need to install Fugue on the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest Solution :

```
df1=df.sort(asc('Timestamp')).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list('Value').alias('newcol'))

+---+---------------+
| id|         newcol|
+---+---------------+
|Id1|[100, 300, 200]|
|Id2|          [433]|
+---+---------------+

df1.withColumn('newcol',concat_ws(";",col("newcol"))).show()

+---+-----------+
| id|     newcol|
+---+-----------+
|Id1|100;300;200|
|Id2|        433|
+---+-----------+
```

Comment: Are you sure sorted order is preserved after the groupby? Really curious. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167750/sort-and-then-groupby-a-dataframe-is-the-sorting-order-preserved-after-the-gro