# How do I coalesce rows in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

In PySpark, there's the concept of `coalesce(colA, colB, ...)` which will, per row, take the first non-null value it encounters from those columns. However, I want `coalesce(rowA, rowB, ...)` i.e. the ability to, per column, take the first non-null value it encounters from those rows. I want to coalesce all rows within a group or window of rows.

For example, given the following dataset, I want to coalesce rows per *category* and ordered ascending by *date*.

```
+---------+-----------+------+------+
| category|       date|  val1|  val2|
+---------+-----------+------+------+
|        A| 2020-05-01|  null|     1|
|        A| 2020-05-02|     2|  null|
|        A| 2020-05-03|     3|  null|
|        B| 2020-05-01|  null|  null|
|        B| 2020-05-02|     4|  null|
|        C| 2020-05-01|     5|     2|
|        C| 2020-05-02|  null|     3|
|        D| 2020-05-01|  null|     4|
+---------+-----------+------+------+
```

What I should get as the output is...

```
+---------+-----------+------+------+
| category|       date|  val1|  val2|
+---------+-----------+------+------+
|        A| 2020-05-01|     2|     1|
|        B| 2020-05-01|     4|  null|
|        C| 2020-05-01|     5|     2|
|        D| 2020-05-01|  null|     4|
+---------+-----------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 5):

First, I'll give the answer. Then, I'll point out the important bits.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, dense_rank, first

df = ...  # dataframe from question description

window = (
    Window
    .partitionBy("category")
    .orderBy(col("date").asc())
)
window_unbounded = (
    window
    .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
)

cols_to_merge = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ["category", "date"]]
merged_cols = [first(col, True).over(window_unbounded).alias(col) for col in cols_to_merge]
df_merged = (
    df
    .select([col("category"), col("date")] + merged_cols)
    .withColumn("rank_col", dense_rank().over(window))
    .filter(col("rank_col") == 1)
    .drop("rank_col")
)
```

The row-wise analogue to *coalesce* is the aggregation function [*first*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first). Specifically, we use *first* with `ignorenulls = True` so that we find the first non-null value.

When we use *first*, we have to be careful about the ordering of the rows it's applied to. Because [*groupBy* doesn't allow us to maintain order within the groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50012355/9526514), we use a [*Window*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window).

The window itself must be unbounded on both ends rather than the default [unbounded preceding to current row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window.rangeBetween), else we'll end up with the `first` aggregation potentially running on subsets of our groups.

After we aggregate over the window, we alias the column back to its original name to keep the column names consistent.

We use a single *select* statement of *cols* rather than a for loop with `df.withColumn(col, ...)` because the select statement greatly reduces the query plan depth. Should you use the looped *withColumn*, you might hit a stack overflow error if you have too many columns.

Finally, we run a `dense_rank` over our window --- this time using the window with the default range --- and filter to only the first ranked rows. We use dense rank here, but we could use any ranking function, whatever fits our needs.