# spark array_sort with complex schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sorting, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I get a dataframe with schema as below：

```
root
|-- clip_id: string (nullable = true)
|-- frames: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
|    |    |-- frame_id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- data_source_info: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
|    |    |    |    |-- data_source_path: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- sub_rules: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- device: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- file_type: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- md5: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is my code， and my spark version is 3.0.2

```
data.select("clip_id", "frame_id", "data_source_path", "sub_rules", "device", "file_type", "md5")
.withColumn("data_source_info", struct(col("data_source_path"), col("sub_rules"),col("device"),col("file_type"), col("md5")))
.drop("data_source_path", "sub_rules", "device", "file_type", "md5")
.groupBy("clip_id", "frame_id")
.agg(collect_list("data_source_info").as("data_source_info"))
.withColumn("frames", struct(col("frame_id"),col("data_source_info")))
.sort(col("clip_id").asc,col("frame_id").asc).groupBy(col("clip_id")
.agg(collect_list("frames").asc_null_first.as("frames"))
```

what I want is to sort the frames by frame_id, but i got error like this:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 37.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 37.0 (TID 2447, 10.134.64.140, executor 39): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: input[1, array<struct<frame_id:string,data_source_info:array<struct<data_source_path:string,sub_rules:array<string>,device:string,file_type:string,md5:string>>>>, true] ASC NULLS FIRST
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Unevaluable.eval(Expression.scala:301)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Unevaluable.eval$(Expression.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SortOrder.eval(SortOrder.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedUnsafeProjection.apply(InterpretedUnsafeProjection.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator.$anonfun$generateResultProjection$5(AggregationIterator.scala:259)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:32)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:658)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$takeOrdered$2(RDD.scala:1492)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:837)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:837)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:462)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

another way of using udf:

```
def frameIdSort(frames: WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema]): WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema] = frames.map(x => (x.getAs[String]("frame_id"), x)).sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```

but also got another error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema is not supported
```

so what i can do to sort the column frames by frame_id?

Comment: Can you add the Spark version to the description please?

Comment: @Chris  thank you for helping， the spark version is  3.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `Cannot evaluate expression: input[1, array...` means that you cannot use `asc_nulls_first` inside `agg` (or `select` for that matter). It is an expression describing how a dataframe should be sorted and can only be used inside an `orderBy` or `sort` function.

What you seem to want however is not to sort the dataframe but to sort an array column inside the dataframe. For that, you can use `array_sort` and since you want to sort by `frame_id`, which is the first element, you don't have to change anything in the rest of the code:

```scala
data.select("clip_id", "frame_id", "data_source_path", "sub_rules", "device", "file_type", "md5")
    .withColumn("data_source_info", struct(col("data_source_path"), col("sub_rules"),col("device"),col("file_type"), col("md5")))
    .drop("data_source_path", "sub_rules", "device", "file_type", "md5")
    .groupBy("clip_id", "frame_id")
    .agg(collect_list("data_source_info").as("data_source_info"))
    .withColumn("frames", struct(col("frame_id"),col("data_source_info")))
    // .sort(col("clip_id").asc,col("frame_id").asc)
    .groupBy(col("clip_id")
    .agg(collect_list("frames") as "frames")
    .withColumn("frames", array_sort(col("frames")))
```

NB: I commented the sort because group by does not maintain order (See [does groupBy after orderBy maintain that order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505599/spark-dataframe-does-groupby-after-orderby-maintain-that-order)). You may put it back at the end if you like.

Comment: Have you tried? It works for me with exactly the same schema.

Comment: @Oil, Thank you for your reply. But column frames is not orderable for its complex schema，it will get an error some like "sort_array does not support sorting array of type xxx(a complex schema) which is not orderable  "

Comment: yes i tried, my real schema is   struct<frame_id:string,rtk:string,data_source_info:array<struct<data_source_path:string,datasource_created_at:timestamp,backup_path:string,datasource_date:string,device:string,file_type:string,md5:string,quality:array<string>,datasource_size:bigint,source_md5:string,source_path:string,source_region:string,sub_rule_scores:map<string,double>,sub_rules:array<string>,datasource_timestamp:string,undistorted:boolean,undistortion:string,datasource_updated_at:timestamp,triage_tags:array<string>,annotation_class:string,info:string,issue_type:string>>> is do not work

Comment: it really worked  in my example

Comment: I got it. its the column sub_rule_scores who's schema is map<string,double> that is not orderable

Comment: So you mean that it works with the example you provided but not with your full data? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Oil yes， because the full data schema has a column of map[String, double] type, and this column is not orderable, it works after I cast the map to string。

Comment: ok, glad you could find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

this usally works for me:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_exploded = df.select("clip_id", F.explode("frames").alias("frame_data"))

df_sorted = df_exploded.orderBy("clip_id", "frame_data.frame_id")

df_final = df_sorted.groupBy("clip_id").agg(F.collect_list("frame_data").alias("frames"))

df_final.show(truncate=False)
```